# HP Vertica - cannot connect and copy from different cluster

Tags: networking, vertica

I'm trying to migrate a Vertica cluster.

The connect statement succeeds:

```
CONNECT TO VERTICA mydb USER myuser PASSWORD '' on 'private-ip',5433;
```

The copy does not:

```
COPY otherdb.whatever FROM VERTICA mydb.table.whatever;
ERROR 4534:  Receive on v_otherdb_node0002: Message receipt from v_otherdb_node0005 failed [canceled]
ROLLBACK 4236:  One or more nodes did not open a data connection to this node.  This may indicate a network configuration problem.  Check that the private interfaces used for communication among the cluster hosts reside in the same subnet and are returned first by host address lookup
```

/etc/hosts on both clusters are configured correctly so that `hostname` maps to `private-ip` across all machines. Telnet, ping, netcat connectivity is all good.

I have tried various options:

- Use identical catalog and data paths in case a mismatch is not tolerated
- Use the same db name and different db names - no difference

The 2 clusters have 6 machines each, and each cluster is healthy and all nodes are up and responsive.

Any suggestions on what else I can try?

Comment: Can you telnet from one to another ? on the 5433 on all nodes ?

Comment: I discovered the issue, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that one of the clusters had been set to EXPORT ON a different subnet than the private subnet.

Doing netcat, I discovered that:

- My new cluster was sending the old cluster it's correct private node IPs
- The old cluster was responding with it's node public IPs, even though "select * from nodes;" was returning the private IPs

From this I ran:

```
select * from vs_subnets;
select database_name, export_subnet from databases;
```

It turns out somebody (long ago) had configured the old cluster to use the public subnet.

You can revert this by running:

```
ALTER DATABASE <my-db-name> EXPORT ON DEFAULT;
```

This makes the DB go back to its regular subnet.